# Restringir forma de inserir em tabelas SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Olá, eu tenho um banco de dados na qual eu salvo umas informações do estabelecimento em uma tabela e em seguida as informações do endereço do mesmo, em outra tabela. Gostaria de saber se tem como eu restringir da seguinte forma. Se as informações do endereço ( por exemplo ) não for inserido por qualquer motivo, o sql excluir o registro que ele fez referente ao estabelecimento.

```
  CREATE TABLE empresa (
  idEmpresa serial,
  cliente_idCliente INTEGER NOT NULL,
  razaoSocial VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  nomeFantasia VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  cpfCnpj VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  ativo INTEGER,
  dataAdesao Date,
  PRIMARY KEY(idEmpresa),
  CONSTRAINT fk_empresa_cliente FOREIGN KEY (cliente_idCliente) REFERENCES cliente (idCliente)
);

CREATE TABLE endereco (
  idEndereco serial,
  empresa_idEmpresa INTEGER NOT NULL,
  nome VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  numero INTEGER,
  complemento VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  cidade VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  estado VARCHAR(2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idEndereco),
  CONSTRAINT fk_endereco_empresa FOREIGN KEY (empresa_idEmpresa) REFERENCES empresa (idEmpresa)
);
```

Atualmente o meu script de criação esta desse jeito.

PS: Eu utilizo o banco Postgres.

//------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//inserir estabelecimento

```
conexaoBD.conexao();        
        try {
            PreparedStatement pst = conexaoBD.con.prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE empresa SET razaosocial=?,nomefantasia=?,cpfcnpj=?,dataadesao=? where cliente_idcliente=? and idempresa=?");
            pst.setString(1, estabelecimentoBeans.getRazaoSocial());
            pst.setString(2, estabelecimentoBeans.getFantasia());
            pst.setString(3, estabelecimentoBeans.getCpfCnpj());
            pst.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(estabelecimentoBeans.getDataAdesao().getTime()));
            pst.setInt(5, estabelecimentoBeans.getIdCliente());
            pst.setInt(6, estabelecimentoBeans.getId());
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados do estabelecimento alterados com sucesso!!!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nao foi possivel alterar o estabelecimento !!!");
        }
        conexaoBD.desconecta();
```

//inserir endereço

```
conexaoBD.conexao();

        try {
            PreparedStatement pst = conexaoBD.con.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO endereco (empresa_idempresa,nome,numero,complemento,cidade,estado) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst.setInt(1, enderecoBeans.getIdEmpresa());
            pst.setString(2, enderecoBeans.getEndereco());
            pst.setInt(3, enderecoBeans.getNumero());
            pst.setString(4, enderecoBeans.getComplemento());
            pst.setString(5, enderecoBeans.getCidade());
            pst.setString(6, enderecoBeans.getEstado());
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados inseridos com sucesso!!!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nao foi possivel salvar o endereco \n" + ex);
        }
        conexaoBD.desconecta();
```

Comment: Você ainda não tem o código que insere as informações? Esse que você postou é apenas o SQL das tabelas.

Comment: @CarlosAndrade está ai o código que eu utilizo para inserir

Comment: Estes procedimentos são feitos em ocasiões diferentes? Por exemplo: O estabelecimento é cadastrado hoje e o endereço amanhã? Ou são na mesma requisição?

Comment: https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/postgresql-job-scheduler   pensou em um job que verifique esta falta e delete o registro pai ? Eu faria um aviso via email e enviaria aos usuarios para que corrijam a questão     http://manojadinesh.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-send-e-mail-from-postgresql_29.html?m=1

Comment: @CarlosAndrade são feitas quase que simultaneamente. Se cadastra o estabelecimento e logo a pois o endereço mas para o usuário foi tudo de uma vez só.

Comment: Anderson, pois veja se é possível realizar os dois inserts numa única requisição. No Firebird, eu utilizo `execute statement 'insert into tabela 1 (campos) values (valores); insert into tabela 2 (campos) values (valores);';` ou `execute block`.

Comment: @CarlosAndrade eu não consegui fazer isso no postgres, ai eu estou no caso verificando se o endereço foi inserido pq se nao foi ele vai voltar e excluir o registro do ultimo estabelecimento automaticamente